# Can I use dense foam board instead of paver base for laying patio pavers?

Tags: patio, pavers

I was told blue dense styrofoam that they use for housing walls would work the same as the expensive EZ Base. Thoughts?

Comment: Drill holes for drainage. Just trying to save money possibly. You get a dense styrofoam equivalent to the ez base. I’d think a large sheet would heave up a lot less that 20 ez base sheets . E z base is only small for transportation marketing

Comment: Kyle, who was that comment directed at? If it's clarifying information it should be added to your question post, not in a comment.

Comment: How did it pan out? I am in the same boat, and am doing a 10X30 patio in South Texas. The Paver boards would cost an excess of $600 where as the pavers and sand would only cost $550. I would like to know how it worked out if you went that route.

Answer (score 1):

Who told you that? I'm sure it wasn't a professional! If that was the case, don't you think everyone would use Styrofoam? Sure you can use Styrofoam (polystyrene) but the pavers will be uneven in no time since Styrofoam is fairly soft. Does it get cold where you live? Styrofoam won't get rid of water which will freeze up and heave up your pavers. Plus it will probably void any warranty the pavers might have or installation warranty.

Paver panels (ez base as you call it) are made specifically for pavers. They are made from polypropylene (a dense plastic) which distribute the weight of each Paver and each step you take. They have channels in the surface to help drain the water away.

Comment: Yes, extruded foam will break down under even foot traffic and begin to collapse.

Answer (score -1):

The only issue would be drainage but they bury styrofoam all the time under highways. It’s not going anywhere and is structurally sound. Of course it’s 3 feet thick, but you can’t drive on those paver panels either. Look close at those paver panels. It’s black styrofoam. You could even take a router and cut your own water channels in styrofoam. I agree at $13 a panel it’s too expensive.

This isn’t rocket science folks. It’s a brick patio. Worst case you have to take it up but it won’t be because the foam broke down. That stuff will last a million years.

One more thing. You want polystyrene not styrofoam. They sell those and you can router it.

Comment: And void a warranty? Lol They’re pavers. You put patio furniture on them and walk on them. Again. Not rocket science. Nobody cares about a paver warranty. What next warranty on gravel?!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear how this answers the question. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Your comment should be [edit]ed into your answer - it doesn't make much sense to just add a comment to your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Insulfoam R-1.9 0.5-in x 4-ft x 8-ft 1 Faced Polystyrene = $8

Brock 2-ft x 3-ft Polypropylene Paver Base Panel = $13

Do the math =>  Spend $8 per 32 SF Insulfoam or $70.

I'm doing a 20ftx8Ft (160 SF) paver patio, need (5) 4x8 Insulfoam = $40
Brock Panel 2x3 would require 27 x $13 = $340

As an architect, this is a no-brainer!  It supports you and some pavers, NOT a car or elephant! Rigid foam is used in ground on concrete foundations so it's durable, even in wet and freezing conditions! Don't believe the fancy marketing!  It's just some pavers to lay down fabric, spread some sand, slap some cheap pavers on top!

I think I'm going to save $300 to do my paver patio!

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please feel free to [edit] your answer to apply the same professional care and proofreading to it that I'm sure you do to your architectural work. Also, it would be good to take the [tour] so you know how to best take advantage of the Question & Answer format here, as it differs from the "standard" discussion format at other sites. Also, bear in mind that pricing is different in different parts of the world and can change day by day. I would imagine, though, that the relative prices of the 2 products would be similar no matter where one goes, so the comparison is valid.